# What's this component and how could these screws affect it?

Tags: identification, high-frequency

Today, I was seeing the circuit of an LNB deeply and a part of it catched my attention. Here is an image of the circuit:
[image: image1]
And here is two images of the bottom and the two components that catched my attention(red circles):
[image: image2]

[image: image3]
There is two screws(Machine screw?)(green circles) that you can screw them up/down and this causes to get them close/far to the components.

Questions:

1- What are these two components?

2- How do they work? and what do they do in this circuit?

**Added:**

Two other images:

[image: image4]

[image: image5]

Also I have a demounted one that took from another LNB. Here is several image:

[image: image6]

[image: image7]

[image: image8]

Please note that this component is not soldered on the PCB, it looks it is glued to the PCB using a red glue as you can see in the images.

Comment: they look like pressure sensors adjustable with the screws but that's just a guess on the pictures. what is the tool? what does it do? does it make sense to be able to adjust it? something like an air intake?

Comment: @Jak As I said it's an LNB. LNB of TV satellite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_block_downconverter

Comment: @Roh Thanks for the explanation, I was just about to ask what it stood for (In France LNB means "Ligue Nationale de Basket": Basketball National League)... You shouldn't use TLAs too much.

Comment: @dim TLAs are a part of english language. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole assembly including those ceramic blocks is what is known as a set of coupled [“Tunable, dielectric-loaded microwave cavities”](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1125720) the white cylinders are ceramic dielectrics that interact with the air dielectric in the metal cavity to create a high-Q tuning structure.

The screws are not mere capacitors, but these alter the physical characteristics of the cavities to change their frequency and Q-factor.

Answer (score 5):

They are tuning screws. They alter the capacitance to ground of the circuit. They are either altering the centre frequency of filters or oscillators.

They will be set up in the factory once the box has been assembled. Once you've opened the box, there'll be no guarrantee you will get it back together with exactly the same position, so you may need to readjust the tuning screws to get back to correct performance.

Comment: Thank you. That should be the answer but could you please add more explanations or add a link about this component?

Comment: Ah! I've just looked at the other photo. They could be dielectric resonators, but it's difficult to be sure with such a poor photo. Can you take and post a new picture with them shown more clearly please. Dielectric resonators will also be tuned by C to ground, but with much less sensitivity than an LC would be, as they tend to be much higher Q. Dielectric resonators are to GHz what piezo crystals are to 10-100MHz. A DR is 'just' like a high Q LC tank circuit, but because it's such high Q, it can be field coupled at quite a distance, as these appear to be.

Comment: Several images added.

Answer (score 0):

It is no component, but as Neil explained a capacitor to ground made out of one part which is the housing and the other part is a PCB area. By adjusting the screw you simply change distance between housing to PCB.